# Filling in an 8x8 minesweeper grid with mines (Day 9: Complex mines)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

<sub>Contains: Complex mines ($i$ mines, where $i:=\sqrt{-1}$), Anti mines (-1 mines)</sub>

<sub>Note: This is in conjunction with my [Minesweeper puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A86115+is%3Aq+%22filling+in+an+8x8+minesweeper+grid+with+mines%22)</sub>

<sub>Sorry for not posting a Minesweeper puzzle yesterday. I will try my best to get Day 10 and 11 out tomorrow</sub>

---

So the gimmick today is that there are complex mines! What is a complex mine, you may ask? Well, a complex mine is $i$ mines, where$$i:=\sqrt{-1}$$The reason we are including anti mines here (where an anti mine is equal to (-1) mines, you can learn more about them on Day 16 of the Minesweeper Advent Calendar [here](https://heptaveegesimal.com/2018/advent-calendar/)) The general definition of an anti-mine is a mine that counts (-1) mines towards a tile, which in some cases can result as a tile having a total of 0 mines that the tile "sees". (a total of $n$ mines added to $n$ anti-mines, where the total of anti mines "seeable" by a tile is the same of the total of regular mines (single, double, triple mines) "seeable" by a mine) Here is the puzzle:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | 4i | 4i |  |
|  | -6+i |  | -3+5i |  |  |  |  |
| -2 |  |  |  |  | 6i |  | 5i |
| -2 | -6 |  | -4+3i | -1+3i | 5i |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | -1+3i |  | -2+3i |
| -4+i |  | -8 |  | -3+i | -2+2i |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | -3+2i | -3+2i |  | -5 |
| -2+i |  | -5 |  |  |  |  |  |

If I have counted correctly, there are 18 complex mines and 17 anti mines.

Note that there are no numbers that have been removed to make this gimmick more easily understandable.

Comment: −1. This puzzle doesn't explain what an anti mine is, nor what it means to take the square root of a mine, and as far as I can tell they're not standard terms. Solving it seems to be impossible without that info.

Comment: @msh210 Ah my bad, I'll fix that quickly

Comment: rot13(Gur gjb $4v$f ba gur gbc evtug zhfg or pbzcyrgryl pbirerq va $v$-zvarf.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot twist!

> It is not uniquely solvable, the top left corner could be either an additional "i" on just the -3+5i and -6+i respectively, or the two in the middle could have one "i" and one "-1". The ol' minesweeper non determinism-eroo

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | *i* | 4i | 4i | *i* |
| - | -6+i |  | -3+5i | *i* | *i* | *i* | *i* |
| -2 | - | - | *i* | *i* | 6i | *i* | 5i |
| -2 | -6 | - | -4+3i | -1+3i | 5i | *i* | *i* |
| - | - | - | - | *i* | -1+3i | *i* | -2+3i |
| -4+i | - | -8 | - | -3+i | -2+2i | - | - |
| *i* | - | - | - | -3+2i | -3+2i | - | -5 |
| -2+i | - | -5 | - | *i* | *i* | - | - |

Comment: didn't hide table behind spoiler cause I wasn't sure how to.

Comment: ah dang it, it's not uniquely solvable again :( but yeah good job

Comment: @CrSb0001 I recommend you go through and solve your puzzles yourself before posting. It's the easiest way to check both difficulty and whether the solution is unique

Comment: for example an easy fix would be putting either a -1+2i or a -2+i in the 3rd square and adjusting the -6+i and -3+5i accordingly.